# How to name a function like this?

Tags: python, function, data-structures, tree, nodes

The pseudocode is like this:

```
def a_func(parent_node, child_node):
    parent_node.add(child_node)
    // check validity
    return child_node

node1 = a_func(pnode, Node(attr_x = "a new node")
node2 = a_func(pnode, Node(node1.get_attr("attr_x"))
```

It's used in tree structure. `a_func` insert nodeX into a parent nodeY and return nodeX. Does anyone have ideas about a suitable name for it?

Comment: Um, maybe `insertNode`?

Comment: @Volatility it's ok, but it might imply that it returns the parent_node..

Comment: Just say in the docstring that it returns the child node... If people don't read it then it's their problem.

Comment: Probably more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would name the function something like `enlistForParent` or maybe `addToParent` or even `setParentForNode` I believe all these versions imply that the return value is the child note and also make the effect of calling the function clear.